# How to show total cost across all orders per customer? (subquery)

Tags: mysql

I want to show the total cost of their order and show each item they bought as well. When I sort by order number the sum(price) gets messed up. And when I sort by customer name it only shows one product. How do I show all the products they purchased and total cost for those products. *Each order has one product attached to it. With a unique order number

These are fictions tables I created that closely resembles my own.

```
Customer Table
+------+-------------+
| name | customer_id |
+------+-------------+
| Adam |           4 |
| Drew |           6 |
| Tom  |           8 |
+------+-------------+
```

```
Order Table
+---------------+---------------+----------+--------------+
| purchase_date | delivery_date | order_id | customer_id  |
+---------------+---------------+----------+--------------+
| 01/22/2020    | 02/23/2020    |        3 |             4|
| 01/12/2020    | 02/12/2020    |        5 |             4|
| 01/31/2020    | 02/22/2020    |        6 |             4|
| 01/05/2020    | 02/14/2020    |       11 |             8|
| 01/22/2020    | 02/23/2020    |        7 |             8|
| 01/12/2020    | 02/12/2020    |        8 |             6|
| 01/31/2020    | 02/22/2020    |        9 |             6|
| 01/05/2020    | 02/14/2020    |       10 |             6|
| 01/05/2020    | 02/14/2020    |       10 |             6|
+---------------+---------------+----------+--------------+
```

```
Product_order table
+-------+------------+----------+
| po_id | product_id | order_id |
+-------+------------+----------+
|     1 |          3 |         3|
|     2 |         13 |         5|
|     3 |          7 |         6|
|     4 |          8 |        11|
|     5 |         45 |         7|
|     6 |          9 |         8|
|     7 |          3 |         9|
|     8 |         45 |        10|
|     9 |          3 |        10|
+-------+------------+----------+
```

```
product table
+------------+------------+-------+
| product_id |  product   | Price |
+------------+------------+-------+
|          3 | Soda       | 7.00  |
|         13 | Chips      | 9.00  |
|          7 | GummyBears | 11.00 |
|          8 | IceCream   | 3.00  |
|          9 | Pen        | 2.00  |
|         45 | Gum        | 1.00  |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

This is the query I tried but produced the result below.

```
select c.name, product, sum(p.price) as total_sale
from (Select distinct order_id, customer_id
    from `order`) as o
inner join (select o.customer_id
    from `order` o
    group by o.customer_id) as a on o.customer_id = a.customer_id
inner join product_order po on o.order_id = po.order_id
inner join customer c on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
inner join products p on po.product_id = p.product_id
group by c.name
```

this is the result:

```
+----------+------------+-----------------+
|   Name   |  product   | total_purchased |
+----------+------------+-----------------+
| Adam     | Soda       |            27.00|
| Tom      | IceCream   |             4.00|
| Drew     | Pen        |            17.00|
+----------+------------+-----------------+
```

I want to show all the products they bought. And the total they purchased all the items for, like so.

```
+------+------------+-----------------+
| Name |  product   | total_purchased |
+------+------------+-----------------+
| Adam | Soda       |            27.00|
| Adam | Chips      |            27.00|
| Adam | GummyBears |            27.00|
| Tom  | IceCream   |             4.00|
| Tom  | Gum        |             4.00|
| Drew | Pen        |            17.00|
| Drew | Soda       |            17.00|
| Drew | Gum        |            17.00|
| Drew | Soda       |            17.00|
+------+------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Can you also give us the **complete** data that produce your result, you have basically to havethe hole price before joining and then remove the group by.

Comment: @nbk I added tables for clarity.

Comment: I don't get it. Adam has just one order with one product (GummyBears). How does he ends up with 3 products in the resultset?

Comment: @Ryan really not trying to be nit picky, but the data you have listed in your table does not match what you want your result set to be (IE: the products `IceCream` and `Pen` don't exist in your tables). To make it easier, can you mock up your tables (with data) and your query on either db-fiddle.com or sql-fiddle.com so we have a working example of what you are seeing? Having your data mocked up on one of those sites will make it easier for others to assist you in getting the answer to your question. here's an example of how to mock it up https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wbNZfuvnVEeT5ceQ9QZrYK/0

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak I added more data to the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data don't fit with the wanted result, but that is only a small problem

Order is a reserved word in mysql, so please try not to use them at all

The dates in your example are also not mysql standard, so i had to rewrite them

It is as i said, you have to calculate the total sum before joining it to the colplte Query

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Customer  (
>   `name` VARCHAR(4),
>   `customer_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Customer 
>   (`name`, `customer_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('Adam', '4'),
>   ('Drew', '6'),
>   ('Tom', '8');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `Order`  (
>   `purchase_date` DATETIME,
>   `delivery_date` DATETIME,
>   `order_id` INTEGER,
>   `customer_id` INTEGER
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `Order`
>   (`purchase_date`, `delivery_date`, `order_id`, `customer_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('2020-01-22', '2020-02-23', '3', '4'),
>   ('2020-01-12', '2020-02-12', '5', '6'),
>   ('2020-01-31', '2020-02-22', '6', '6'),
>   ('2020-01-05', '2020-02-14', '11', '8');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Product_order (
>   `po_id` INTEGER,
>   `product_id` INTEGER,
>   `order_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Product_order
>   (`po_id`, `product_id`, `order_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '3', '3'),
>   ('2', '13', '5'),
>   ('3', '45', '6'),
>   ('4', '7', '11');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE products (
>   `product_id` INTEGER,
>   `product` VARCHAR(10),
>   `price` DECIMAL(5,2)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO products
>   (`product_id`, `product`, `price`)
> VALUES
>   ('3', 'Soda', '3.99'),
>   ('13', 'Chips', '7.99'),
>   ('45', 'Gum', '8'),
>   ('7', 'GummyBears', '12');
> ```

> ```
> select o.customer_id, sum(p.price) as total_sale
> from (Select distinct order_id, customer_id
>     from `Order`) as o
> inner join Product_order po on o.order_id = po.order_id
> inner join products p on po.product_id = p.product_id
> group by o.customer_id
> ```
>
> ```
> customer_id | total_sale
> ----------: | ---------:
>           4 |       3.99
>           6 |      15.99
>           8 |      12.00
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     c.name, p.product, pr.total_sale
> FROM
>     Customer c
>         INNER JOIN
>     `Order` o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
>         INNER JOIN
>     Product_order po ON o.order_id = po.order_id
>         INNER JOIN
>     products p ON po.product_id = p.product_id
>         INNER JOIN
>     (SELECT 
>         o.customer_id, SUM(p.price) AS total_sale
>     FROM
>         (SELECT DISTINCT
>         order_id, customer_id
>     FROM
>         `Order`) AS o
>     INNER JOIN Product_order po ON o.order_id = po.order_id
>     INNER JOIN products p ON po.product_id = p.product_id
>     GROUP BY o.customer_id) pr ON c.customer_id = pr.customer_id
> ```
>
> ```
> name | product    | total_sale
> :--- | :--------- | ---------:
> Adam | Soda       |       3.99
> Drew | Chips      |      15.99
> Drew | Gum        |      15.99
> Tom  | GummyBears |      12.00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc22aba87ead042965ffd8feadceb37c)*